# GitHub invitation of a developer with access restriction

Tags: github

I want to invite an external developer to a private repository. This developer should be allowed to do nothing in the master and nothing in the stage branch. Only in the devel branch he should be allowed to commit.

In the section "Settings" I selected the tab "Branches".
There I created a branch protection rule for the branch "master" and "stage".

I tried to follow these instructions:
https://help.github.com/en/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions
But I can't find the option "Restrict who can push to this branch".

What do I have to do to realize my request?

Comment: Is the repository part of an organization, or is it owned by an individual user?

Comment: Looks like the wording has changed to 'Restrict who can push to matching branches'. Do you see that at the bottom of the 'Rule settings' list?

Comment: It is individual user, not an organization.

Comment: @JakeWorth I don't see it.

Comment: Does the description "[o]rganization owners and people with admin permissions for organization-owned repositories" describe you and your repo?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the account into a organization. Then there it is possible to add protection rule to the branches.